# Select a value from MySQL database only in case it exists only once

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

Lets say I have a MySQL table that has the following entries:

```
1
2
3
2
5
6
7
6
6
8
```

When I do an "SELECT * ..." I get back all the entries. But I want to get back only these entries, that exist only once within the table. Means the rows with the values 2 (exists two times) and 6 (exists three times) have to be dropped completely out of my result.

I found a keyword DISTINCT but as far as I understood it only avoids entries are shown twice, it does not filters them completely.

I think it can be done somehow with COUNT, but all I tried was not really successful. So what is the correct SQL statement here?

Edit: to clarify that, the result I want to get back is

```
1
3
5
7
8
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to mix GROUP BY and COUNT().

Assuming the column is called 'id' and the table is called 'table', the following statement will work:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(id) = 1
```

This will filter out duplicate results entirely (e.g. it'll take out your 2's and 6's)

Comment: You don't need the `WHERE 1`

Comment: This is closest to what I'm doing. I have a WHERE statement with some conditions there plus a randomising function plus a limit-function. I appended my "ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 24" at the end. The result: the grouping does not work, I still get some results that exist twice. I'd guess it is caused by the LIMIT statement somehow. So how can I let the GROUP/HAVING statement apply to the whole dataset while LIMIT does influence the result only?

Comment: Hmm, that should work. I just tried : `SELECT * FROM 'test' WHERE 1 GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(id) = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3` and it still returned only unique results.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `COUNT()` in combination with a `GROUP BY` and a `HAVING` clause like this:

```
SELECT yourCol
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY yourCol
HAVING COUNT(*) < 2
```

[Example fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e9b6/1/0)

Comment: +1. Thanks for sqlfiddle, I didn't know such a nice thing existed.

Answer (score 2):

Three ways. One with `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT columnX
FROM tableX
GROUP BY columnX
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 ;
```

one with a correlated `NOT EXISTS` subquery:

```
SELECT columnX
FROM tableX AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM tableX AS t2
        WHERE t2.columnX = t.columnX
          AND t2.pk <> t.pk             -- pk is the primary key of the table
      ) ;
```

and an improvement on the first way (if you have a primary key `pk` column and an index on `(columnX, pk)`:

```
SELECT columnX
FROM tableX
GROUP BY columnX
HAVING MIN(pk) = MAX(pk) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select id from foo group by id having count(*) < 2;
```